# APEX installation fails, PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.DBMS_DB_VERSION' must be declared

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-xe

Trying to install Oracle APEX 20.2 on Oracle XE 18c database following [official instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/htmig/downloading-installing-Oracle-AE.html#GUID-7E432C6D-CECC-4977-B183-3C654380F7BF) but I receive error when running `@apexins.sql SYSAUX SYSAUX TEMP /i/`

```
...set_appun.sql
    $if sys.dbms_db_version.ver_le_10_2 $then
        *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-06550: line 9, column 9:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.DBMS_DB_VERSION' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 8, column 37:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 9, column 9:
PLS-00174: a static boolean expression must be used


Disconnected from Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0
```

Looks like DBMS_DB_VERSION is missing/not declared?

I connected successfully sys as sysdba, altered session to PDB database and ran the command but was stopped. When looking in my sys tables, I see DBMS tables but [no DBMS_DB_VERSION table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqLYb.png) . Shouldn't it be there if code requires it? I've checked sys and system schemas, nowhere to be found.

Before coming to this, I had issue where I didn't know I should alter to PDB, so I tried running installation against CDB, where I was stopped and had to alter, not sure if it relates.

Any ideas how to go around this? Is this issue with XE edition only?

Comment: See if this (https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4323567/solved-apex-19-2-install-fails-on-db-19-3-se2-with-pls-00201-id-sys-dbms-db-version-must-be-dec) helps.

Comment: Thanks, I checked that out earlier but I can't interpret the answer. Even if I'm interpreting it correctly, it asks to alter PDB to OPEN state, which doesn't work and is probably cause to this issue as well. (explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67463205/cannot-alter-pdb-to-open-state-throwing-error-ora-00604-error-occurred-at-recu)

Comment: Had to reinstall DB to resolve and successfully install APEX.

Comment: Thank you for letting us know.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the reason for me was that the pluggable database was closed, so I had to open it before doing anything thus do the following

```
SQL> alter session set container = orclpdb;
SQL> alter pluggable database open;
SQL> @yourfile.sql
```

then run your @yourfile.sql and use your container's name, it may be something other than orclpdb, this depends on your installation