# Cannot Alter PDB to Open state, throwing error ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-xe

Oracle XE 18c database, had failed APEX installation which apparently set my (only PDB) to Mounted and now I can't move it back to Read only/Open.

`ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE XEPDB1 OPEN;`

```
Error starting at line : 8 in command -
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE XEPDB1 OPEN
Error report -
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01405: fetched column value is NULL
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
           (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
           can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
```

Tried all solutions known to me, via SQL*Plus and SQL Developer to no avail. Tried creating new PDB but it can't as existing one is not in OPEN. Tried using startup command, received same error but nothing in specific:

```
SQL> startup
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01405: fetched column value is NULL
```

In case DB got corrupted somehow, would this be resolvable with reinstall of XE DB?

Comment: It would be easier to drop and recreate your PDB

Comment: See if this helps: https://ahmedfattah.com/2020/05/02/alter-pluggable-database-open-ora-00604-ora-01405-after-apex-installation/

Comment: Is there any database trigger?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov - I tried creating another PDB database but it's not allowing me, with error ORA-65036: pluggable database PDB$SEED not open in required mode. If I drop PDB database, will I be able to create another PDB?

Comment: @mathguy - Thanks, it describes exact issue I'm having BUT in my case - apxremov.sql doesn't seem to work, same error as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67462560/apex-installation-fails-pls-00201-identifier-sys-dbms-db-version-must-be-dec. It's throwing it upon installing or trying to uninstall APEX.

Comment: @AmanSinghRajpoot There are some default triggers and trigger which I created to alter pluggable database to open on startup, which doesn't work, trying startup on PDB throws same error as described in question.

Comment: Take the backup of the triggers and drop them and try again with your statement

Comment: If it has nothing to do with triggers then try reinstalling Apex

Comment: Reinstalled Database and resolved the issue. Nothing else worked.